# Using HTML, how do I link to a website I don't own that doesn't use www?

Tags: html, url, flash

My problem is that I'm trying to link to a flash game on a version of the site with no www. HTML doesn't recognize it without www. If I use the www version I and everyone else using the app would have their savegames reset. What can I do?!

Edit: I had been testing via TideSDK Developer but decided to try Chrome. Magically it works as it should. Sorry for the trouble everyone I guess it wasn't HTML's fault after all.

Comment: Please show us your code because this makes no sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the full link including 'http://'

So for example, if you wanted to add a link to example.com, you would use 
`<a href="http://example.com/">Link to Example.com</a>`

Also, the website you are trying to link to might automatically add the 'www.example.com' after the user connects to the site via a redirect.

Comment: Thats what I've got configured currently and still no dice. I'm positive the site doesn't redirect and have proven it via url bar. Thanks for replying!